# Definite Integral of a infinitesimal

Tags: calculus, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I did not study math, but have some foundations in it. I have been looking through some books on nonstandard analysis, and have (what I consider to be) a pretty simple question which I haven't been able to answer through my reading thus far.

Let $\epsilon$ be an infinitesimal as described by Abraham Robinson. Consider the expression:

$\int_{a}^{b} \epsilon$

1) Does this expression even make sense?

2i) If it does make sense, is there a way of calculating what it evaluates to?

2ii) If it doesn't make sense, is there another (rigorous) discipline which can evaluate the quantity?

I would greatly appreciate any direct answers or references to (reasonably easy to read) materials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes as much sense as, say, $\int_a^b 2$ does — or $\int_a^b 2 \rm{d}x$  if the former looks too weird. As with the example just shown, in $\int_a^b \epsilon$ you're using $\epsilon$ as a shorthand for the constant function $x\mapsto\epsilon\colon[a,b]\to {^*}\Bbb R$. The value of the expression is $(b-a)\epsilon$.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, & thank you. (oops on my part: ${^*}\Bbb R$ not $\Bbb R$ -- corrected.)

Comment: This answer is arguably technically incorrect.

Comment: If we have an ordered field with infinitesimals, every finite Riemann sum for the function $f(x) = \epsilon$ on the interval $[0,1]$ will add up to $\epsilon$, and thus according the definition of the Riemann integral, we would indeed get $\int_0^1 \epsilon\,dx = \epsilon$. This is also the area of a 1 by $\epsilon$ rectangle. Unfortunately, the way nonstandard analysis is often presented changes the definitions of derivatives and integrals, making it impossible to compute such things with the definitions *as they are presented in that context*; this is what the other answer is points out.

Comment: Mummert, the integral is by definition the standard part of an infinite Riemann sum and therefore apriori does not take non-real values.  Learn something about nonstandard analysis before confusing editors here.

Comment: As I wrote. that is *one* definition of an integral. The integral is also "by definition" the limit of Riemann sums, and this particular integral should also be the area of a particular rectangle. There is nothing confusing about the fact that some presentations of nonstandard analysis use alternative definitions that no longer match the geometry of the nonstandard field that is being used.

Comment: @CarlMummert, this is a very puzzling comment.  You can't work with two different definitions of the same mathematical comment simultaneously.  How do *you* define the integral?  You seem to want to *define* the integral of a constant function as the product of that constant by the length of the interval. This is certainly reasonable, but it does not give you a reasonably general notion of derivative.  In that sense such a definition would be useless, and certainly not something the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite correct, because integral as it is usually defined is applied to an ordinary real function and produces (in the case of a definite integral) always a *real* number.  So it is not merely a difference of notation between the sloppy notation $\int_a^b 2$ and the more careful notation $\int_a^b 2dx$.

Infinitesimals (and especially infinitesimal partitions) are ordinarily used in defining definite integrals in a fashion that is intuitively appealing and is closer procedurally to what the inventors of the calculus (like Leibniz and Euler) were doing, but they are usually only an intermediate step, and tend to disappear when the final answer is produced.  This is true for the definition of the derivative as much as the definition of the integral.

One can further generalize this to apply to more general functions (such as the constant function equal to an infinitesimal $\epsilon$ as you envisioned) but such a generalisation is more delicate and usually involves an understanding of the notion of an internal set. This properly belongs in analysis in Robinson's framework and pretty much does not occur in the calculus.

In short, you typically won't need such integrals when studying the calculus but if you would like to understand Robinson's framework in more detail, the starting point will probably be the notion of an internal set.

Comment: If $a$ is infinitesimal, surely $\int_0^1 a\,dx = a$.  One of the disadvantages of some presentations of nonstandard analysis, as mentioned in this answer, is that although they enrich our picture of the real line with infinitesimals, they are not able to handle simple questions such as this integral, or related questions such as "what is the derivative of the function $y = x^2$ at an infinitesimal point?". These presentations relegate infinitesimals to second-class status, in a way.

Comment: Mummert, your comment is inaccurate, as I indicated in my answer. This integral can indeed be evaluated rigorously, but this requires a somewhat more delicate analysis. In response to your comments on relegating infinitesimals to "second-class status", I note that I find your comments decidedly second-class in quality. The value of the derivative of the function $y=x^2$ is a straightforward matter, unlike the integral you claim is "surely $a$".

Comment: I mentioned "some" sources, and in particular I was thinking of the way that Keisler's text handles derivatives. If I recall correctly, the only method he gives for computing them is only valid for standard inputs. I have been told that one viewpoint some have about nonstandard analysis is that within calculus we are primarily interested in "real" objects, and (accordingly) the values of the derivative or integral at nonstandard inputs are of secondary interest.  That viewpoint could make it hard to see why the original question here is interesting from a purely geometrical point of view.

Comment: @CarlMummert, the basic principle in Keisler's book *Elementary calculus* is the extension principle (and after than the transfer principle). Namely, each real function $f$ has a (unique) natural extension $f^{\ast}$ to the hyperreals. Once we differentiate a function, say $x^2$, to get $2x$, the new function (in this case $2x$) has a natural extension which is defined on the hyperreals, and in particular at an infinitesimal point.  On the other hand, the matter with the integrals is more involved.  Therefore you will never find an integral of an infinitesimal in Keisler's book...

Comment: ... I can elaborate further in terms of the superstructure as to why this is the case, but I think this will not be a novelty to you.